# Install Wildfly using Galleon

Tags: transactions, ejb, wildfly

I installed minimal Wildfly distribution using Galleon with following command

```
galleon.sh install wildfly:current --layers=jaxrs,cdi,web-server,logging,management,core-management --dir=wildfly
```

Bellow is the component I got in my application server

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.core-management"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.elytron"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
```

I realized that there is no ejb3,transactions in the configuration file "standalone.xml"

```
org.jboss.as.ejb3
org.jboss.as.transactions
```

I did research and read all the document in Galleon, I could not find the proper syntax to install ejb3 and transaction
I tried the following command

```
galleon.sh install wildfly:current --layers=jaxrs,cdi,web-server,ejb3,transactions,logging,management,core-management --dir=wildfly
```

but Galloen did not recorgnized ejb3 and transaction

Any idea or source that  I can take a look to install wildly with ejb3 and transaction using Galleon ?

- Galleon version : 3.0.2
- Wildfly version : 16.0.0 Final

Answer (score 0):

Transactions will be pulled if yo use the 'jpa' layer.
For ejb3 I didn't see it in any layer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have layers for ejb3. We defined layers to address lightweight servers.
jaxrs and cdi layers depend on web-server, you don't need to install it, it will be included when you include jaxrs or cdi.

Comment: Thank you @jean-francois Denise. That mean if I want to use EJB3 I can not intall by using Galleon. I will need to use a full Java EE  Wildfly distribution version download from here https://wildfly.org/downloads/ ?

Comment: You can install using Galleon: galleon install wildfly:current --dir=myserver, This will install all configurations. If you only want standalone.xml, use the option --default-configs=standalone/standalone.xml

Comment: Hi @jean-francois Denise  I think you missed the point of above question. I want to build a minimal distribution of Widfly. This command galleon install wildfly:current --dir=myserver   --default-configs=standalone/standalone.xm install full distribution for standalone.

Comment: For minimal installation you need layers. So yes, you can't.